# Save the state of switch using essential.prefences in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to save the state of a switch in Xamarin.forms even when the user close the application, I followed the Microsoft tutorial about the Xamarin essentials  preferences API tutorial[Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ls4PKU55U4&list=PLM75ZaNQS_Fa6UdCieXUcVubIV3-MDXDV&index=31&t=0s). Below is the switch code in Xaml and Xaml.cs

```xml
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" IsVisible="True" Margin="50,10">
    <Label Text="Remember Me:" />
    <Switch IsToggled="{Binding SwitchMe}" />
</StackLayout>
```

```cs
public bool SwitchMe
{
    get => Preferences.Get(nameof(SwitchMe), false);
    set
    {
        Preferences.Set(nameof(SwitchMe), value =true);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SwitchMe));
    }
}
```

Problem:
The switch state will return to its defaults when the application is closed.

Is there a problem in my code ?
I have added all the requirements in the android and ios for xamarin.essentials.

Comment: Why are you writing `value = true`?

Comment: Just to check if it will change the state after closing the app

Comment: have you checked that the preference is set correctly when resuming the app?

Comment: @Jason How to check that? sorry I am new in Xamarin world

Comment: use the debugger like you would with any C# project

Comment: the value still false even if  I change the switch to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys, the solution was like the following:

```
 public bool SwitchMe
    {
        get => Preferences.Get(nameof(SwitchMe), false);
        set
        {

            Preferences.Set(nameof(SwitchMe), value);
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SwitchMe)));
        }
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer , which will help more people who has similar issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Reference `Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences` directly from the Property in your ViewModel:

```cs
public bool SwitchMe
{
    get => Preferences.Get(nameof(SwitchMe), false);
    set
    {
        Preferences.Set(nameof(SwitchMe), value);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SwitchMe));
    }
}
```